# Prestashop: use global theme translations in module override

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1. I created template overrides for some Prestashop modules and would like to only work with the translations from my theme.

If I add an string in a template override from a module (without the mod parameter):

`{l s='Thank you for your order!'}`

I can't translate this string because it is not visible in the backoffice's translation page.

Is this simple not possible or am I'm making a mistake?

Comment: did you try to clear the cache? and delete class_index.php located in the cache folder?

Comment: Yes I've already deleted the cache & and class_index.php but the translations still now appear in the backoffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override a module template you should use `mod` parameter. If not, Prestashop Translator will not locate this string as part of a translated text inside module. 
Without `mod` you could maybe find it frontoffice or backoffice translations.

Note: Take into account that Prestashop first take translation from theme if exist, them from Prestashop core if exist and them from module translation if exist. If none of these exist default text is shown (should be in english)

Good luck.